# String.init(contentsOfFile:) replacement for Linux?

Tags: swift, string, file, swift3, foundation

After deploying my Swift 3 app to Heroku, it crashed with the following error:

```
fatal error: init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:) is not yet implemented: file Foundation/NSString.swift, line 1255
```

What can I use instead of `String.init(contentsOfFile:)` on Ubuntu?

Comment: It's a damn shame that Apple doesn't provide this basic functionality ... I need to lose my time figuring this out and importing a third-party lib for supporting this ...

Comment: I don't know if the answer worked for you, but in case it didn't there is an oper-source swift package `FileUtils` that is a wrapper upon C std, like fopen, fwrite, etc. which supports basic functionality like creating, reading and writing files :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seeing the latest source code of Swift Standard Library, `String.init(contentsOfFile:)` internally calls `NSString.init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:)`. ([NSStringAPI.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSStringAPI.swift))

And the Linux version of `NSString.init(contentsOfFile:usedEncoding:)`, as you see, is not implemented yet. ([NSString.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSString.swift))

Seems `NSString.init(contentsOfFile:encoding:)` is already implemented and `String.init(contentsOfFile:encoding:)` calls it. So, if you know the encoding of the file, use `String.init(contentsOfFile:encoding:)` like:

```
let fileContent =  try? String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
```

If you do not know the string encoding of the file, you may need to implement the functionality by yourself.